# Free or kill Lorenzo?

Tags: fallout-4

What will happen as a result of the choice to free/kill Lorenzo? Will he just attack me if I free him? I watched a video where he was freed and when he went to kill his family, he attacked the player but discussions said he would just kill his family... so what's the truth?

Comment: This is not an opinion based question, I disagree with those close votes. This is asking about a specific end to a specific quest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THIS ANSWER CONTAINS SPOILERS**

All of this information can be found on the Wiki page for the quest ["The Secret of Cabot House"](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Secret_of_Cabot_House). Let me break it down.

The end result result of the quest will be one of two things:

1. You kill Lorenzo, one way or the other.
2. You save Lorenzo, killing his family in the process.

These are the only ways the quests can end. To answer your question though, the ONLY time that he will attack you is when you have chosen option 2, and then choose **NOT** to help him kill his family. Siding with his family or attacking him at all after he is freed will cause him to be aggressive towards you. Else, he is either dead or friendly towards you.

Hope this helps!